Understanding the NE602 Colpitts oscillator
I'm trying to understand how the Colpitts LC tank circuit in Philips' application note AN1982 for the NE602 works. Both the application note and the datasheet show that pins 6 and 7 provide access to an NPN transistor with an 18K resistor from base to VCC and a 25K resistor from emitter to ground (https://docs.rs-online.com/3cf1/0900766b80027aa2.pdf see Figure 2 on pg. 2)

My question is, why is there no resistor from the base to ground for proper transistor biasing? When I simulate this, the circuit oscillates, but the waveform is clamped and distorted.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I do not know why I can't simulate it in CircuitLab. However, the same circuit with the same values etc. simulated in LTspice looks like this


And the waveform on pin 6 looks like what?

I've added the results from a LTspice simulation.

That looks about as good as it gets for the simple common-collector Colpitts oscillator. You might also try loading pin 6 with possibly 100 kohm because it's pin 6 that is used internally in the NE/SA602.

Shouldn't there be another resistor from base to ground to properly bias the base of that transistor?

You are making big (and likely false) assumption that the circuit shown is fully representative of all components. Have you listened to what I said about the loading on pin 6 due to internal circuits?


My question is, why is there no resistor from the base to ground for
proper transistor biasing?

Firstly, the emitter resistor is 20 kΩ and not 25 kΩ (as shown in an image from the file you linked): -

I've added the red box.
Secondly, notice the connection from pin 6 to a buffer amplifier. This will load pin 6 towards ground more than likely and thirdly, read this in the document you linked: -

In red (my addition) are the words you should read carefully and understand. The implication of these words are that the pull-up resistor shown on pin 6 to Vcc (pin 8) may be slightly different internally hence it doesn't introduce power supply noise and, I take this to mean that the actual bias given to pin 6 is more complex than a simple resistor.
In other words, you can't look at the circuit shown in the data sheet and expect to decipher what is actually happening inside the chip. I mean, why should Philips (the original supplier from memory) give you that IP?
